# CCSpriteBatchNode : is there a performance gain for animations

Tags: performance, cocos2d-iphone

When a texture contains the frames for a single animation, is there any performance gain going via a CCSpriteBatchNode for creating the animation ?  I guess you will never draw two sprites at the same time, and there is no real 'batching' involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCSpriteBatchNode allows you to draw much more faster big amount of sprites. So, in case of just single sprite with frame animation there should be no difference at all.

Comment: That would have been my guess also, but there is so much hype over the batching, i am wondering whether i'm missing something fundamental over the underlying GL stuff (above my head). There is quite a stiff price to pay with the batchNode's use restrictions, and i want a definitive answer to this before committing even a controlled experiment.

Comment: the main and the only thing that batch node do is that it draws all it's children in a single draw call. It doesn't translate visit method to it's children. You can look to the CCSprite's draw method there is even an assertion that says, that draw cannot be called if sprite is added to the batch node. so, it is really very useful with big amounts of sprites to draw. in case of one sprite, it will be one draw call anyway - CCSprite's draw or CCSpriteBatchNode's one

Comment: yes, i saw that. However, i saw recently Stefen posting something about having significant performance gain for one large texture (like a background image), and that got me wondering whether the batchNode was actually doing something basically different in the draw that could attract a gain for a single texture.

Comment: can you post the link to this article? the one i've found, contains only thought about drawing large background with repeating one big texture several times. here this article http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/

Comment: Thanks for interesting article above, seems to go in the direction 'no gain' for a single (large) animation spritesheet. Still looking for reference, will update.

Comment: accepting this answer although i did not get the specific information i was looking for. Enough trolling, now i will measure it :)